# Show that $\sum (p\log(p))^{-1}$ converges

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Show that 
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty (p_k\log(p_k))^{-1} \mbox{ converges.}
$$
Here $p_k$ is the $k$th prime number.

This is in Elementary number theory. I tried doing the integral test but I was not given bounds on the summation so I did not know the bounds on the integral.

Comment: "I was not given bounds on the summation." Don't you think that's important for deciding if the series converges???

Comment: I don't know if it will help, but I believe p is prime. I really do not have much information besides that.

Comment: Well, then maybe a good start is to get some clarification from whoever assigned you this problem. We aren't mindreaders.

Comment: General suggestion: never try to prove any statement until it's an actual statement. It's really tough to prove the statement $x < 7$. It's not so hard when you're asked to show that *if* $x = 6,$ *then* $x < 7$.

Comment: I edited the question to clarify: $p$ here stands for "prime"; summation is for all prime numbers.

Comment: It is enough to invoke a weak version of the PNT, namely $p_k \gg k\log k$, to get that the wanted series is convergent by Cauchy's condensation test.

Answer (score 2):

[Rosser proved](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rosser_theorem) that the $k$th prime is greater than $k\log k$, and
[Dusart proved](http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1999-68-225/S0025-5718-99-01037-6/) even more:
$$
p_k > k(\log k + \log\log k -1) \qquad\mbox{ for }k\ge 2.
$$
Therefore each partial sum of your series 
$$
\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty {1\over p_k \log p_k}
$$
is bounded by the respective partial sum of
$$
\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty {1\over k\log k \log p_k}
$$
which is in turn bounded by
$$
\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty {1\over k\log^2 k}.
$$
The latter series converges.